# Create a bar graph with Ploty express using a python dict

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar graph in plotly express using data that has been filtered and looks like `{item_a: 1, item_b: 33, item_c: 47}` in python. It doesn't have an index. How can I make this data into a bar graph showing `item_*` on the x axis and the sum on the y axis?

Comment: you can use matplotlib 
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = {'item_a': 1, 'item_b': 33, 'item_c': 47}
plt.bar(data.keys(), data.values())`

Answer (score 2):

Easier if you use graph_objects instead

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {"item_a": 1, "item_b": 33, "item_c": 47}

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=list(data.keys()), y=list(data.values())))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

**plotly express** simplest input is a data frame.  Just create one.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {"item_a": 1, "item_b": 33, "item_c": 47}

px.bar(pd.DataFrame(data, index=["key"]).T, y="key")
```